# Hard drive not visible in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I installed a 2nd hard disk and at first it wasn't visible in Disk Management but I managed to solve that myself. In the BIOS there are checkboxes which SATA ports are activated and it turned out SATA-0 was deactivated. So I activated it that solved it. So now my hard disk is recognized and visible in Disk Management as Disk 1. It has 4 volumes:

```
2.38 GB Healthy
2.00 GB Healthy
128 MB Unallocated
1858.51 GB Healthy
```

- Right clicking the Healthy volumes only shows one option: Delete Volume. The rest is greyed out.
- Right clicking the Unallocated volume shows one option: New Simple Volume.

This is a used hard disk. It used to be in a Synology NAS which makes it Linux formatted, I guess.

What seems strange to me is that 2nd hard drive does not seem to show up when using diskpart. I see it in Disk Management but it ain't there in diskpart. Weird?

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: DELL-T3500-PC

DISKPART> list volume

Volume ### Ltr Label Fs Type Size Status Info
---------- --- ----------- ----- ---------- ------- --------- --------
Volume 0 D DVD-ROM 0 B No Media
Volume 1 System Rese NTFS Partition 100 MB Healthy System
Volume 2 C Win7 NTFS Partition 931 GB Healthy Boot

DISKPART>
```

What you see there is my DVD and my 1st hard disk (System Reserved + C drive).

Perhaps I should put it back into a Synology NAS and format it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the existing data on the Disk, you are in for a hard time. It might be easier to use Linux (e.g. in a virtual machine) to mount it and extract the data, but a Google search for "ext3 windows driver" will point you in the right direction.

If you just want to reformat the drive, "Delete Volume" is what you want - for every visible volume. You can then create one or more new volume(s) and assign a drive letter.

Comment: No need to read the data. But thanks for asking! :-)

Comment: So just use "Delete Volume" on all volumes, then create a new one and it will work as expected.

Comment: Gotcha!  :-)  What about that 128 MB Unallocated volume? Right click, select New Simple Volume, assign a drive letter, delete it and extend some other volume?

Comment: When you have removed the adjacent volumes, the unallocated space will merge with the newly created unallocated space.